# java program unable to authenticate against ldap

Tags: java, ldap

I have written a small program to authenticate against  ldap.

```
import javax.naming.*;
import javax.naming.directory.*;
import java.util.Hashtable;

class SAuth {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Hashtable env = new Hashtable(11);
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, 
        "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://xx.xx.xx.xx:yyyy/");

    // Authenticate as S. User and password "mysecret"
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "username");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "cn=orcladmin");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password");

    try {

        DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
            System.out.println(" i guess the connection is sucessfull :)");

        // Do something useful with ctx 

        // Close the context when we're done
        ctx.close();
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

}
}

I get the following error :

```
javax.naming.AuthenticationNotSupportedException: orcladmin
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.sasl.LdapSasl.saslBind(LdapSasl.java:100)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.authenticate(LdapClient.java:214)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(LdapCtx.java:2658)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.<init>(LdapCtx.java:287)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURL(LdapCtxFactory.java:175)

        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURLs(LdapCtxFactory.java:193
)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxInstance(LdapCtxFactory.ja
va:136)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getInitialContext(LdapCtxFactory.jav
a:66)
        at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:6
67)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:288
)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:223)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:197)
        at javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.<init>(InitialDirContext.jav
a:82)
        at Simple.main(Simple.java:28)
```

But , if i try to access ldap directory using ldap cmd line and same user credentials , it works smoothly. 
for example:

```
ldapsearch -p <port> -h <ip> -D "cn=orcladmin" -w "password"  objectClass=*
```

returns concerned data. 
I guess there is something wrong with the java program , but dunno wat .

Comment: Probably duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209710/authenticationnotsupportedexception-digest-md5-on-websphere

Comment: Also, check out http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PQ72729

Comment: Artem: I am trying to connect to Oracle Internet Directory`s ldap. i doubt whether the settings are same as webspheres.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try chaning

```
env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "username");
```

to

```
env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
```

Comment: it worked .. finally.  is there any books which explain various ldap concepts and APIs using Java ?

Comment: There is an immense JNDI Tutorial at oracle.com including a major section on LDAP.